# PHP table output partial output from MSSQL database

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, html-table

This is for a school project and I cannot figure out why, but it only returns two columns.  The picture of the database I am querying is:

[image: http://imgur.com/MDxgwzQ].

Since the screenshot I have changed the NULL fields to 1, thinking that it wouldn't print NULL.

The webpage of this project is on [my project](http://breadwinka.com/celeri/main.php).

Before the step of building the table, I did test to see what the array returns, and it was exactly what I expected.  There were blanks for the NULL values from the previous database.  I am thinking that it could have been the numbers that is stopping it from returning the rest of the arrays, but the commands I am using, IIRC(If I ReCall), return only strings to the arrays.  I might not be correct, but that is my understanding.

REMEMEBER: NULLs in the database image linked are now 1's(int type).

I have not used a framework, I am doing this all inline coding (for experience).  This is the first time using PHP.  I have looked at many other examples, but I can't seem to adapt their solutions to my own problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I forgot to print the array output from my testing.  It is *(Almost same url as above, just remove main.php and add test.php)*, I forgot to mention that the NULL fields that are varchar data typed were replaced with NA instead of 1's I have edited the image to reflect this.

```
    <?php
    require_once(file is there...) // removed from example for security reasons.
    // Test message
    echo '<p>Connect please...</p>';

    try {
        //  Connection from PHP to MSSQL via PDO
        // DataBase Host
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

        //Sent/Send To Host and preparing the query to send.
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Backbar");

        //Send that query!
        $result = $sth->execute();

        // Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set 
        $row = $sth->fetchAll();

        // Used to move through array.
        $subarraypos = 0;

        // Start the table format extravaganza!
        print('<table border="1px">');
        print('<tr><th>ProductCompany</th>
               <th>ProductName</th>
               <th>Barcode#</th>
               <th>Color</th>
               <th>Perms</th>
               <th>Cost</th>
               <th>Volume</th>
               <th>Size</th>
               <th>Shelf Location</th>
               <th>Shelf Cap</th>
               <th>Quantity On Hand</th>
               <th>Storage Location</th>
               <th>Quantity In Storage</th>
               <th>Vendor</th>
               <th>Vendor Region</th>
               <th>Vendor Mileage</th>');
    foreach($row as $value) {
        if($subarraypos === 0) {    
            print('<tr><td>'.$value[$subarraypos].'</td>');
            $subarraypos++;
        }

        //  16 will reset the number of columns from the
        //  database so each entry is correctly shown.
        //  Else of first if(...) (Elif)

        if($subarraypos <=15) {
            print('<td>'.$value[$subarraypos].'</td>');
            $subarraypos++;
        }
        //  Else of second if(...)  (Else)
        $subarraypos = 0;
        print('</tr>');
    }
    print('</table>');
    print('<p>'.$row.'</p>');
    print('<p>'.$value.'</p>');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo "<p>You should see a table, unless I broke it.</p>";
unset($dbh);
?>
```

Comment: You are calling a foreach loop to loop over the rows, but not looping over the contents of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to loop over the subarray. It will do the call for subarraypos = 0 and subarraypos = 1, then move to the next row of the table.

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
    print('<tr>')
    for ($subarraypos = 0; $subarraypos < 16; $subarraypos++) {
        print('<td>' . $value[$subarraypos] . '</td>')
    }
    print('</tr>')
}
```

Comment: What does the above output? Have you tried adding `print_r($row)` after the `fetchAll()` call to see what is actually in the array you are printing?

Comment: Yes, I printed that before in a test.  [This is the page](http://breadwinka.com/celeri/test.php).  The above doesn't even get to the "Connect Please..."

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a for loop inside of another for loop(for(for())), this printed everything in two tables so far.  I actually changed it instead of a foreach(for()) inside the PHP print(...).  Now it is just a function I made, and it works 100%.

The only problem I am having now is the output is supposed to be in a tabbed pane via jQueryUI/jQuery.  Both have been linked .js and .css have been linked, one at a time of course.  If you know what I should do, the URL is the same as above.(main.php)